# PayPal gateway has rejected request. A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed (#10736: Shipping Address Invalid City State

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

I have paypal as the defaultmethod payment and i have created an account with wrong information so when i procced to pay wiith paypal it show me this message :
PayPal gateway has rejected request. A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed (#10736: Shipping Address Invalid City State
how can i fix this?!! thansk in advance

Comment: You need to use proper address in your shipping address during checkout.

Comment: do you mean for the account of customer or paypal ??

Comment: Account of customer from which you are placing an order.

Comment: ok thanks !! so no need for proper informations for paypal ?

Comment: You need to put also correct information in admin under shipping settings. Correct information not needed for paypal account if you are using sandbox account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83164/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-developper-magento).

Comment: thanks SuKumar you are right it was about the wrong adress that i passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message states that you have put wrong address for shipping during checkout.

Paypal accepts correct address everytime you place an order. If the address you are using for shipping is not valid then paypal rejects it with the error message you are getting.

For other payment gateways its fine. There are some payment gateway who validates your city, postcode, state and country. If these details are not correct then they will reject the payment and give you error message.

So better to test paypal you need to fill up valid shipping address during checkout.

Comment: yes exactly that 's it